# . How to update individual database elements with SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

Good evening everyone, this is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "Users.db";
private static final String DB_TABLE = "Users_Table";

//Colonne
private static final String ID = "ID";
private static final String NAME = "NAME";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE+" ("+
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";

public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_TABLE );

    onCreate( db );
}

public boolean updateData(int id, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(  );
    contentValues.put( NAME, name );
    contentValues.put( ID, id );
    db.update( DB_TABLE, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf( id )} );
    db.close();
    return true;

}

//Metodo per inserire dati
public boolean insertData (String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(  );
    contentValues.put( NAME, name );

    long result = db.insert( DB_TABLE, null, contentValues );

    return result != -1;  //Se il risultato è = -1 i dati NON vengono inseriti
}
    //Metodo per cancellare i dati
    public int deleteSelectedItem(String NAME) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int result = db.delete( DB_TABLE, "NAME = ?", new String[] {NAME} );
    return result;
    }
//Metodo per visualizzare i dati
public Cursor viewData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "Select * from "+DB_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    return cursor;
}}
```

In MainActivity I call the method like this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton( "Modifica", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                        listItem.set( position, editText.getText().toString().trim() );

                                        db.updateData( editText.getText().toString() );
                                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Elemento modificato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                                    } else {
                                        editText.setError( "aggiungi elemento qui" );
                                    }

                                }
                            } );
```

When I use it, the ListView updates, but when I restart the emulator, the text I had edited, it returns to its original state.
So the method does not update the items in the database. What's wrong with my code? Thanks

EDIT:
This is the viewData method in the Main:

```
private void viewData () {
    Cursor cursor = db.viewData();

    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Nessun dato da visualizzare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            listItem.add( cursor.getString( 1 ) );
            //index 1 è il nome, index 0 è l'ID
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( MainActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listItem );
        userlist.setAdapter( arrayAdapter );

    }
}
```

Comment: The 4th argument of the update() method should be the id of the row that you want to update and not the new name that you want to save in the table.

Comment: You must pass the id of the row that you want to update also to the method updateData() like: `public boolean updateData(int id, String name)` and call update() like this: `db.update( DB_TABLE, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});`

Comment: Perfect, I made the changes you said in my DatabaseHelper, but now in the MainActivity the call "db.updateData (editText.getText (). ToString ());" is wrong, how can I change that too?

Comment: You must add as 2nd argument the integer id of the row which you want to update.

Comment: You mean the second argument of the onClick? Sorry I'm a beginner.
should i replace "int which" with "int id?"

Comment: No, you must call: `db.updateData(id, editText.getText().toString ());` where `id` is an integer variable which has the value of the id of the row that you want to update.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that I, despite having the "insert" and "delete" methods working, have not yet obtained the value of the db row? I don't know how to get this value. Thanks a lot anyway, I have to study a lot

Comment: It's not possible to update a specific row if you don't know the value of the primary key/id of that row.

Comment: The ID value varies based on the item I'm selecting at the time. Is there a command, to be inserted instead of the int number, that says "take the selected id"?
Meanwhile it may be useful to know that in my database there is this:
private static final String ID = "ID";
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE+" ("+
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            NAME+ " TEXT "+ ")";

Comment: When you load all the rows from the table to the list you must also store their ids not only the names, so when you select an item in the list you can get its id. If you don't have the id you can't update.

Comment: First of all thank you for your infinite patience, I begin to understand the logic, but ... what is the part of code in which I load all the rows from the table to the list?
I can't find a totorial to learn this specific passage :(

Comment: What I mentioned about the list is just an example. I don't know what you are actually doing. I assumed that you select an item from a list which has been already filled with the rows of a table and you want to update that item's name. If this is not the case then post your actual code, so I can see what you mean by *the item I'm selecting*.

Comment: Thanks, I will publish my code below.

Comment: Ho pubblicato l'intero DatabaseHelper, hai bisogno anche del MainActivity?

Comment: So you use a spinner to select the names? Also are the names unique? If they are not unique then you can't update without id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of the table so that the column `name` is unique:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE+" ("+
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        NAME+ " TEXT UNIQUE"+ ")";
```

You will have to uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun so that the database and the table are recreated.
Then change `updateData()` like this:

```
public boolean updateData(String currentName, String newName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(  );
    contentValues.put( NAME, newName );
    boolean result = db.update( DB_TABLE, contentValues, NAME + " = ?", new String[] {currentName} ) > 0;
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

So you pass the current name to `updateData()` to find the row that you want to update.
Finally change the listener of the button:

```
builder.setPositiveButton( "Modifica", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            db.updateData( listItem.get( position ), editText.getText().toString().trim() );
            listItem.set( position, editText.getText().toString().trim() );
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Elemento modificato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } else {
            editText.setError( "aggiungi elemento qui" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In the meantime, thank you. I made the changes you recommended, but when I click on EDIT, I get the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: P.S. If I understand correctly the error occurs on this line:
db.updateData( userlist.getSelectedItem().toString(), editText.getText().toString().trim() );

Comment: From the code that you posted I assume that `userlist` is the spinner from which you select the names. You use it in `viewData()` where you load all the names so it can't be null.

Comment: I published under, the main activity

Comment: So it's a ListView and not a spinner. Change `userlist.getSelectedItem().toString()` with `listItem.get( position )`. I edited.